# Doing masters in Political Economy

Tags: self-plagiarism

Is it possible to use part of my thesis proposal to help me write another essay on a different assignment ? Or does this amount to "self-plagiarism"? Essentially in the other assignment I want to use parts of my proposal to answer the question, it is in a similar context but takes the material in a different direction. The proposal is not in anyway published and as far as I am aware of I would be the owner of the copyright in both instances. I understand that there might be an issue of claiming credit twice but I can't see why I can't use some previous material I have written before to support a different argument.

Comment: We can't answer for you. Ask your instructor.